# I tried connecting mysql database to java but i got the exception as "com.mysql.jdbc.Driver"

Tags: java, mysql

Here is my code

```
try
{
    Class.forName("com.mysql.jdbc.Driver");
    Connection conn=(Connection)DriverManager.getConnection("jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306/Hotel_management"+"root"+"1234");
    Statement stmt=conn.createStatement();
    String query="insert into Records(Name, Address, Contact_no, Email, Nationality) values('"+name+"','"+add+"','"+con+"','"+e_mail+"','"+nat+"');";
    stmt.executeQuery(query);
}
catch(Exception e)
{
    JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(this, e.getMessage());
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

set class path to [mysql](http://www.java2s.com/Code/Jar/m/Downloadmysqlconnectorjar.htm) jar file. Since `com.mysql.jdbc.Driver` class available in this jar file.

```
String DB_URL = "jdbc:mysql://localhost/Hotel_management";
String USER = "username";
String PASS = "password";
conn = DriverManager.getConnection(DB_URL,USER,PASS);
```

Comment: Now i'm getting the exception as Access denied for user"@'localhost'(using password: NO)

Comment: use mysql correct username and password in your code.

Comment: I'm pretty sure it is correct.

Comment: Is mysql installed in your current system or you are accessing it remotely.

Comment: It's on the current system.

Comment: Are you able to logging in to Mysql CMD prompt with same username and password.

Comment: which parameters you are passing to getConnection(). post that line here

Comment: "jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306/Hotel_management","root","1901211304");

Comment: GRANT ALL PRIVILEGES ON `*.*` TO 'root'@'localhost' IDENTIFIED BY 'root' WITH GRANT OPTION; use this cmd.

Comment: @Sam, welcome. Accept this answer then this will be useful to others.